# Locked file is stuck in trash

Tags: terminal, finder, permission, trash, macos

I have a file in my Trash.  The filename is 'codedesign' and it is a Unix executable file.  This file ended up there in the process of me trying to fix a corrupted patch installer.  The original version is still in my /usr/bin/ directory and therefore this one would be fine to delete.

The situation looks like this, the file is the only thing that is in my Trash.  When I click empty trash it doesn't show an error message, but it doesn't delete the file.
When I right click the file and select 'Delete Immediately...'  it asks me for my password then comes up with the error message '*The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items.'*

The file permissions say that my user has 'Read & Write' while the Wheel user has 'Read'.  I can't change any permissions without getting an error message saying that I don't have permission to make changes.

I can't put the file back as this option isn't available when I right click.  When I try and drag the file out of the trash it simply makes a copy.

I've tried using the app Trash It! as well as CleanMyMac3 But these do nothing.

The results of the following terminal commands used so far:

```
$ sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
rm: /Users/JamieMacLeod/.Trash/codesign: Operation not permitted
$ ls -ald ~/.Trash/* 
-rwxr-x--x@ 1 JamieMacLeod wheel 86032 31 Oct 2014 /Users/JamieMacLeod/.Trash/codesign
$ xattr -l /Users/JamieMacLeod/.Trash/codesign
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A2 01 02 5F 10 62 68 74  |bplist00..._.bht|
00000010  74 70 3A 2F 2F 64 63 36 35 33 2E 34 73 68 61 72  |tp://dc653.4shar|
00000020  65 64 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 64 6F 77 6E 6C 6F 61 64 2F  |ed.com/download/|
00000030  6A 4C 69 4C 4F 68 38 54 63 65 2F 63 6F 64 65 73  |jLiLOh8Tce/codes|
00000040  69 67 6E 2E 68 74 6D 6C 3F 74 73 69 64 3D 32 30  |ign.html?tsid=20|
00000050  31 34 31 30 33 31 2D 30 32 34 34 33 33 2D 34 32  |141031-024433-42|
00000060  62 64 39 64 63 64 26 6C 67 66 70 3D 32 30 30 30  |bd9dcd&lgfp=2000|
00000070  5F 10 33 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 34 73  |_.3http://www.4s|
00000080  68 61 72 65 64 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 67 65 74 2F 6A 4C  |hared.com/get/jL|
00000090  69 4C 4F 68 38 54 63 65 2F 63 6F 64 65 73 69 67  |iLOh8Tce/codesig|
000000A0  6E 2E 68 74 6D 6C 08 0B 70 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  |n.html..p.......|
000000B0  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000C0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A6                       |.........|
000000c9
com.apple.quarantine: 0001;5543f6cd;Google\x20Chrome;0F73411A-982E-4A8A-B099-93610324B751

$ ls -lO@ /Users/JamieMacLeod/.Trash/codesign
-rwxr-x--x@ 1 JamieMacLeod  wheel  restricted 86032 31 Oct  2014 /Users/JamieMacLeod/.Trash/codesign
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms      201 
com.apple.quarantine       67
```

I'm really not sure what to do that this point, surely there is a way to delete one file?  I am the only user on this computer and therefore should have full admin rights.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The group is showing as restricted - this may indicate that it's due to SIP.

Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768087/restricted-folder-files-in-os-x-el-capitan tells you how to temporarily disable SIP to delete the file.

Could also try `sudo chown [owner]:[group]`? (Although if it is SIP, I don't think that it's this easy to get around).

Comment: Amazing! Disabling SIP sorted it.  Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Most welcome. Glad it helped :)